# Discussion Board Popularity Bar

Tags: discussion-board

I created a new site in SharePoint Online and enabled the Community Features which created a default discussion board and created a new page called Community Home.aspx. This page has a webpart showing the contents of the default discussion list and also shows the popularity bar together with the Likes and Replies for each post.

I created a new discussion board and created a web part in the home page pointing to that discussion board as well but I can't seem to find a way to make it look like the original discussion board with the popularity bar. Any idea on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to make sure the D board has ratings turned on. This is under Ratings settings in the list settings. Then the subject view should show the likes or stars and what we especially wanted: the # of replies. If you were displaying the D board in a web part you may need to edit the web part and "reapply" the view to get it to update.